# How to make LIFX bulbs flicker

Tags: ruby, rubygems, lifx

We bought few LIFX light bulbs and I was asking to write ruby code to make a LIFX flicker based on certain events.

I could not find any example to make it flickering, anyone knows how ? some code example using the official gem would be much appreciated

[LIFX Website](http://au.lifx.co/)

[LIFX Gem on Github](https://github.com/LIFX/lifx-gem)

Comment: There is sample code on the Github site, so what didn't work when you tried using it? Or did you ask before trying?

Comment: Turn them on or off works fine, set_color works fine, I did not find any methods to make them flickering. If you see any please let me know

Answer (score 1):

once you have installed the lifx gem you can try this:

```
require 'lifx'

# set the label of the bulb you want to "flicker"
label = 'YourBulbLabel'
client = LIFX::Client.lan

# find the light with the label you have set in your LAN
client.discover! do |c|
    c.lights.with_label(label)
end

# turn on the lights
client.lights.turn_on

light = client.lights.with_label(label)

# make it flicker
light.set_color(LIFX::Color.hsbk(259, 0.1, 0.5, 5000), duration: 1)
sleep 1
light.set_color(LIFX::Color.hsbk(259, 1, 1, 5000), duration: 1)
sleep 1
light.set_color(LIFX::Color.hsbk(259, 0.1, 0.5, 5000), duration: 1)
sleep 1
```

hope this gets you started
the documentation helped me a lot: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/lifx/lifx-gem/master/LIFX/